# How to annotate builder-like DSL structure?

Tags: groovy

I have in my application severals DSL implemented with groovy builders. I'd like to support annotations in some node, by example :

```
builder.define {

  @Secure
  checkService {
    ... 
  }

}
```

However, this script is not syntaxically correct and it doesn't compile (I can't annotate an invokation of a method).

Is it possible to implement this kind of DSL in Groovy, with an AST transformation or any other methods ? If yes, does anybody have an example ?

I use temporarily properties, like `checkService(secure:true)`, but it's not really pretty...!

Comment: or `secured { checkService {}}`

Answer (score 1):

Annotation cannot be placed at a `MethodCallExpression`. Even the [new Groovy 3 Syntax](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_3_0_0_ALPHA_1/src/antlr/GroovyParser.g4) won't allow this.

As cfrick said, you'll have to look for other options.

## Plain groovy with closures and omitted braces

You can create a similar syntax by defining `secure` as a method, returning `Closure` from each method and use groovys optional braces:

```
class Builder {
    def define(@DelegatesTo(InnerBuilder) Closure defineClosure) {
        println("start define")
        def innerBuilder = new InnerBuilder()
        defineClosure.delegate = innerBuilder
        Closure returnedClosure = defineClosure()

        // also call the returned Closure
        returnedClosure.delegate = innerBuilder
        returnedClosure()
        println("end define")
    }

    class InnerBuilder {
        def secure(Closure c) {
            return { ->
                println("start being secure")
                c()
                println("stop being secure")
            }
        }

        def elegant(Closure c) {
            return { ->
                println("start being elegant")
                c()
                println("stop being elegant")
            }
        }

        def checkService(Closure c) {
            return { ->
                println("start checkService")
                c()
                println("stop checkService")
            }
        }
    }

}

def builder = new Builder()
builder.define {
    checkService {
        println "running a service check"
    }
}

println()
println("with secure")
println()

builder.define {
    secure checkService {
        println "running a service check"
    }
}

//    NOT WORKING
//    println()
//    println("with new-line but missing the backslash")
//    println()
//
//    builder.define {
//        secure // this will NOT be secure!
//        checkService {
//            println "running a service check"
//        }
//    }

println()
println("with new-line and backslash")
println()

builder.define {
    // this WILL be secure!
    secure \
    checkService {
        println "running a service check"
    }
}

println()
println("two")
println()

builder.define {
    // needs braces
    elegant secure(checkService {
        println "running a service check"
    })
}

println()
println("Both orders work")
println()

builder.define {
    secure elegant(checkService {
        println "running a service check"
    })
}

println()
println("Multiple with line-break")
println()

builder.define {
    secure \
    elegant(
    checkService {
        println "running a service check"
    })
}
```

Will print

```
start define
start checkService
running a service check
stop checkService
end define

with secure

start define
start being secure
start checkService
running a service check
stop checkService
stop being secure
end define

with new-line and backslash

start define
start being secure
start checkService
running a service check
stop checkService
stop being secure
end define

two

start define
start being elegant
start being secure
start checkService
running a service check
stop checkService
stop being secure
stop being elegant
end define

Both orders work

start define
start being secure
start being elegant
start checkService
running a service check
stop checkService
stop being elegant
stop being secure
end define

Multiple with line-break

start define
start being secure
start being elegant
start checkService
running a service check
stop checkService
stop being elegant
stop being secure
end define
```

## AST transform

This is a bit more complex and I don't think it delivers the value worth the effort, but you could use an AST transform to mitigate the syntax issues of the previous version.

```
class Builder {
    def define(@DelegatesTo(InnerBuilder) Closure defineClosure) {
        println("start define")
        def innerBuilder = new InnerBuilder()
        defineClosure.delegate = innerBuilder
        defineClosure()
        println("end define")
    }

    class InnerBuilder {
        def secure = "just a string"

        def elegant = "just a string"

        def checkService(Closure c) {
            println("start checkService")
            c()
            println("stop checkService")
        }
    }

}

def builder = new Builder()
builder.define {
    secure
    elegant
    checkService {
        println "running a service check"
    }
}
```

Thus far `secure` has no meaning (it's a [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)). You'll need to write an AST Transform to change that. Here `secure` and `elegant` *should* (i.e. not verified) be `VariableExpression` that are inside a `ExpressionStatement` as part of a `BlockStatement` that is the `code` property of the surrounding `ClosureExpression`. Actual implementation is left as an excercise for the reader ;)